# How to make a button to fill the entire grid cell after rotating the button?

Tags: maui

I'm trying to rotate button in MAUI. Without rotating, button perfectly fill nearly whole screen (except place for label). But after rotation it keeps size, so height is much too small (there is a lot of free space) width is much bigger than device width.

```
    <Grid x:Name="Grid"
        Margin="15,15,15,15"
        RowSpacing="15"
        ColumnSpacing="15"
        VerticalOptions="Fill">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="CategoryLabel" FontSize="32" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Button Rotation="90" Text="Play" FontSize="150" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Clicked="OnPlayBtnClicked" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

I was trying with some hard coded values, it looks ok on my device, but probably much worse on other ones. I'm wondering how to rotate this button to make it fill whole grid cell. Maybe there is some way to get maximal size of grid cell, or rotate text only?

Comment: Don't rotate the button, rotate some Label on top of it

Comment: I tried it. It looks pretty good on Android. It is worse on Windows, the label is hiding a button (when I'm clicking the label, the button doesn't catch a Clicked event, but I don't want to add additional events to the label). I'm keeping this solution but I'm wondering if there is some better way.

Comment: You can set on the Label: InputTransparent="True", so only the button will catch the click event

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: I tested above code you shared, the button could catch the clicked event both on android and window. Could you please share the steps of reproducing this problem?